# PHP Russian url encoding

Tags: php, xml, url, simplexml

When using this url-string in Simple_XML - `http://квартиры-домики.рф/Admin/Import/rieltonReport.xml`

I get this error -

```
simplexml_load_file(http://%D0%BA%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D1%8B0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B8.%D1%80%D1%84/Admin/Import/rieltonReport.xml) [function.simplexml-load-file]: failed to open stream: php_network_getaddresses:getaddrinfo failed: hostname nor servname provided, or not known
```

Is is possible to somehow point to the web-site using a url-encoder (tinyurl), or make php understand the russian letters?

Answer (score 1):

If you have installed PHP 5 >= 5.3.0, PECL intl >= 1.0.2 and PECL idn >= 0.1, you can use function

```
idn_to_ascii('домики.рф');
```

for converting domain name. You can read documentation about this functionality here: http://php.net/manual/ru/function.idn-to-ascii.php

If you can't install pecl library, you can use another solution on plain php: http://phlymail.com/en/downloads/idna/

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, there is a standard for writing out domain names in different languages.

An alias for such domain is created - http://xn----7sbfkscajgsvub0a1l.xn--p1ai/.

For Chrome, just have to copy from the browser.